# Remove a list item from list in the item's member function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Say I have a list `list<Item>`, and

```cpp
class Item {
 public:
  Item(list<Item>& l); // l is the list the item is in.

  RemoveItself() {...} // remove this from l.
}
```

When I call `item.RemoveItself()`, it removes itself from the list. If I were to implement this myself, I could have `prev_ptr` and `next_ptr` in the `Item`, and then everything is easy. I am wondering if there is a way to do it using STL?

Comment: Do you want to implement list using pointer or want to get outside operation of STL list like you can push an element or remove an element?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Update to using reference (pointer sounds good too). Just a typo.

Comment: Looks like you might be looking for: `std::list::erase`

Comment: If I implement `list` myself, I know how to do it. But wonder how to do it within stl.

Comment: `std::list::erase` takes an iterator. Does that mean I should store an iterator of this object then? Also, that way I would have to worry when the iterator invalidates (although this is definitely a way as the iterator of `list` is valid when the container changes).

Comment: @365sleeping No, it just means you would have to search for a matching iterator only at the time you actually need it, such as with `std::find/_if()`. Also, `std::list` removals don't invalidate iterators to other list elements, only the `end` iterator and iterator(s) to the removed element are invalidated.

Comment: @365sleeping If `std::list` is not mandatory, I think `std::set<std::unique_ptr<Item>>` might be better. You can easily erase it this way: `item_set.erase(this)` (pseudo-code)

Comment: Regarding using `std::set`, yes I agree. Initially I was thinking about `std::unordered_set` but `std::set` might be closer to what's needed.

Comment: @Sprite Just noticed you changed from shared_ptr to unique_ptr. But that would require custom-defined comparator, i.e. use the raw pointer instead of the unique ptr. Otherwise, item_set.erase(this) would not work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @365sleeping No, that was my mistake. I edited it because I thought `shared_ptr` is a bit heavy, but when I tried to test it with `unique_ptr`, it actually didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Your `list` is holding `Item` *objects*, which are going to be copies of any `Item`s you insert into the `list`.  As such, you would have to use `std::find_if()` and `list::erase()`, or `list::remove_if()`, to remove elements that *compare equal* to `*this`, eg:

```cpp
class Item {
private:
  list<Item> &l;

public:
  Item(list<Item> &l) : l(l) {}

  void RemoveItself() {
    auto iter = std::find_if(l.begin(), l.end(),
      [this](const Item &elem){
        return true/false based on some condition of elem and this representing the same item...;
      }
    );
    if (iter != l.end())
      l.erase(iter);

    // or:
    l.remove_if(
      [this](const Item &elem){
        return ...;
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Which probably isn't what you want.  A list of `Item*` pointers would probably be more appropriate instead (`list<Item*>`), eg:

```cpp
class Item {
private:
  list<Item*> &l;

public:
  Item(list<Item*> &l) : l(l) {}

  void RemoveItself() {
    auto iter = std::find(l.begin(), l.end(), this);
    if (iter != l.end())
      l.erase(iter);

    // or:
    l.remove(this);
  }
};
```

In which case, if the `Item()` constructor adds `this` to the `list`, then it can also save an `iterator` to the new element, and then it can simply remove that element later:

```cpp
class Item {
private:
  list<Item*> &l;
  list<Item*>::iterator l_iter;

public:
  Item(list<Item*> &l) : l(l) { l_iter = l.insert(l.end(), this); }

  void RemoveItself() {
    l.erase(l_iter);
  }
};
```

Comment: note that OP changed their code in the meantime. To be fair, before this answer was posted. Maybe add the original code to the answer

Comment: The missing of reference/pointer is just a typo. The question is more about conceptually how to use the STL to implement the O(1) remove object itself of linked list.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I removed the whole first paragraph, since it no longer applies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Yes, `list<Item>` would make the comparison hard yet `list<Item*>` means I have to hold the item somewhere else. Ideally, the item should be GC'ed after removing itself.

Comment: C++ does not have garbage collection. The real question is, *who* owns the `Item` objects? Why is `Item` trying to manage itself in the `list` to begin with? That is usually not a good idea.  Whoever is putting `Item`s into the `list` should ideally be the one to also remove them. But, if that is not an option, then consider using smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`) instead, let them handle the cleanup for you.